# How to check if an other program is running in fullscreen mode, eg. a media player

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog, fullscreen

How can I check if an other app is running in full screen mode & topmost in c++ MFC?
I just want to disable all of my auto dialogs (warnings) if media player or other players are running. (Like silent/gamer mode in Avast.)
How could I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

using a combination of EnumWindows, GetWindowInfo and GetWindowRect does the trick.

```
bool IsTopMost( HWND hwnd )
{
  WINDOWINFO info;
  GetWindowInfo( hwnd, &info );
  return ( info.dwExStyle & WS_EX_TOPMOST ) ? true : false;
}

bool IsFullScreenSize( HWND hwnd, const int cx, const int cy )
{
  RECT r;
  ::GetWindowRect( hwnd, &r );
  return r.right - r.left == cx && r.bottom - r.top == cy;
}

bool IsFullscreenAndMaximized( HWND hwnd )
{
  if( IsTopMost( hwnd ) )
  {
    const int cx = GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXSCREEN );
    const int cy = GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYSCREEN );
    if( IsFullScreenSize( hwnd, cx, cy ) )
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}

BOOL CALLBACK CheckMaximized( HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam )
{
  if( IsFullscreenAndMaximized( hwnd ) )
  {
    * (bool*) lParam = true;
    return FALSE; //there can be only one so quit here
  }
  return TRUE;
}

bool bThereIsAFullscreenWin = false;
EnumWindows( (WNDENUMPROC) CheckMaximized, (LPARAM) &bThereIsAFullscreenWin );
```

edit2: updated with tested code, which works fine here for MediaPlayer on Windows 7. I tried with GetForeGroundWindow instead of the EnumWindows, but then the IsFullScreenSize() check only works depending on which area of media player the mouse is in exactly.

Note that the problem with multimonitor setups mentioned in the comment below is still here.

Comment: So I have to forget your sample code, and should concentrate to these new functions?

Comment: depends on what behaviour you want, there are some caveats: suppose a dual monitor system, an app can be fullscreen on screen 1, but that does not necessarily mean it also has focus since the user can be using another app on screen 2 at the same time. So you have to decide what to do in that case as well..

Comment: The IsFullscreenAndMaximized function returns always TRUE, why?

Comment: Ok, thank you! It's almost done. If I open the Task manager and I maximize it, the function works, but if I open a media player and make it to full screen, it doesn't work. Only if I maximize it and then I make it to full screen. Should I only focus to the WS_EX_TOPMOST ?

Comment: Will not this just compare against the primary screen? If another monitor is introduced with a different resolution I cannot see how this will check that. For a more thorough comparison you would need to compare against the monitor the HWND is on.

Comment: @BuiltonSin yes, as said in the answer and the comments, this might not work as expected on multiple monitor setups

Answer (score 0):

in my oppinion a very little improvement

```
bool AreSameRECT (RECT& lhs, RECT& rhs){
    return (lhs.bottom == rhs.bottom && lhs.left == lhs.left && lhs.right == rhs.right && lhs.top == rhs.top) ? true : false;
}


bool IsFullscreenAndMaximized(HWND hWnd)
{
    RECT screen_bounds;
    GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow(), &screen_bounds);

    RECT app_bounds;
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, &app_bounds);

    if(hWnd != GetDesktopWindow() && hWnd != GetShellWindow()) {
        return AreSameRECT(app_bounds, screen_bounds);
    }

    return false;
}
```

And thanks to priviose answer

```
BOOL CALLBACK CheckFullScreenMode ( HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam )
{
    if( IsFullscreenAndMaximized(GetForegroundWindow()) )
    {
        * (bool*) lParam = true;
        std::cout << "true";

        return FALSE; 
    }
    return TRUE;
}


int main() {

    bool bThereIsAFullscreenWin = false;
    EnumWindows( (WNDENUMPROC) CheckFullScreenMode, (LPARAM) &bThereIsAFullscreenWin );
}
```

Comment: What about multi-monitor setups? How do you distinguish between a window, that has been resized to cover an entire display, and a window that is truly in fullscreen mode? Have you verified that the window rectangle of a maximized window really is the same as the window rectangle of the desktop?

Comment: Note: (lhs.left == lhs.left) should be (lhs.left == rhs.left) in AreSameRECT