# How to detect a non Java program running in fullscreen mode?

Tags: java, cross-platform, fullscreen, detect

I am currently developing a Java cross-platform (windows and mac os x) application running in background and displaying a pop-up window on some user's or system's events like "Copy and Paste" or programs' launching.

Nevertheless, I would like to detect first, if any other program, not necessarily developed in Java, is running in full screen mode. In that case, I would not display my window.
For instance, when user is watching a movie in full screen (media player...), a Powerpoint presentation...

So here are my questions :
1. Is there any way to do such a thing in Java language?
2. If it's not possible, I will do my "full screen mode detector"  in another language but it has to be able to communicate with my Java app to notify the presence of a full screen window.
3. If it's not possible (1) : do you know the best language to do it? I found other solutions in C# or C++ MFC( [How to check if an other program is running in fullscreen mode, eg. a media player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797802/how-to-check-if-an-other-program-is-running-in-fullscreen-mode-eg-a-media-playe) ).

Any idea would be very useful.
Thanks a lot.

Sebastian

Comment: See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/60501359/9192635 I think this is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I did one external program for each OS which checks if active window is in full screen mode or not and writes the result on standard output. My Java app calls the good program according to the OS and read the result.

I used :

- C# for Windows
- Carbon for Mac OS X

The hardest part was Mac OS X version.

Don't hesitate to ask me if you're interested in these programs.

Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can capture screen with java.awt.Robot, can you implement algorithm based on screenshot?

Comment: Interesting answer, thank you. Actually my application already captures a screenshot just before displaying the window. So you think it's possible in an algorithm to analyze the screenshot and determinate if a window is in fullscreen mode? I'm a bit skeptic because sometimes it's hard to say rather you're in full screen mode or not, for instance, watching a movie.

Comment: it's possible with more than 95% accuracy . Watching a movie means you maybe have black rectangle on the top & bottom, and don't have apple/windows logo, framed windows. And yes, it's not easy to implement.

Comment: The only alternative is JNI with implemented function per platform -Windows API,Objective C,X11 etc.

Comment: Thanks again. I think I will study JNI now and develop a function per OS.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to give the user the option of enabling/disabling your pop-ups. That way they can pick and choose when to receive pop ups.

Comment: Thanks for this advice. User can already do it in my program. But I also need to detect full screen programs running because maybe, in the future, I will need to show a particular pop-up on this event. I didn't say it before but my application's goal is to ask user questions about his activity on the system (Descriptive Experience Sampling method).