# Python check if application is in fullscreen

Tags: python

I've shortly startet out learning about python. For my first project I wanted to create a tool that upon checking if a third programm is in fullscreen or not, starts running some functions.
Basicaly, let's say we run a Game, it goes to fullscreen, and then my programm should detect that. How do I get it to do that? (I'm on a Windows Platform)
I've seen some Hints on using the Windows api or installing extensions using .NET framework but am too inexperienced to know how to go on about it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if an other program is running in fullscreen mode, eg. a media player](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797802/how-to-check-if-an-other-program-is-running-in-fullscreen-mode-eg-a-media-play)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the hints by @ivan_pozdeev, this is how I solved the problem.
It checks the screen resolution of the primary screen and compares it against the window size of the foreground window.
For multi-monitor setups, there are the following problems:

- application might be not in foreground -> then you will have to enumerate all windows and check each one
- full screen application might be on any screen -> [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/multiple-display-monitors-functions) might help

```py
from ctypes import windll
import win32gui
user32 = windll.user32
user32.SetProcessDPIAware() # optional, makes functions return real pixel numbers instead of scaled values

full_screen_rect = (0, 0, user32.GetSystemMetrics(0), user32.GetSystemMetrics(1))

def is_full_screen():
    try:
        hWnd = user32.GetForegroundWindow()
        rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hWnd)
        return rect == full_screen_rect
    except:
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Python specifically, that's pure WinAPI. See [How to check if an other program is running in fullscreen mode, eg. a media player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797802/how-to-check-if-an-other-program-is-running-in-fullscreen-mode-eg-a-media-play) for the algorithms. Then look into [`pywin32`](http://pywin32.sf.net) and possibly [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html?highlight=ctypes#module-ctypes) for the appropriate wrappers.

Comment: This is something that can be achieved using Python with the appropriate libraries (such as pywin32, as you pointed out) by someone with no knowledge of the WinAPI or C/C#, definitely related to Python and Python projects

Comment: @SebastianRivas You can't use pywin32 without knowing WinAPI, you wouldn't know how to use the functions. Pywin32 only gives the minimum of info and abstracts very few details away.