# NodeJS detect if any software goes fullscreen (YouTube, Games etc.)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently trying to find out if there is an way in nodejs to detect fullscreen from third-party application?
I'm trying to detect if the PC is idle or not. It's already working very well with keyboard and mouse but I'm now trying to detect if any application is on fullscreen (as example watching video in fullscreen, playing any games or reading pdfs).

I hope someone know a good package for that. :) I couldn't find it.

Thank you

Comment: nodejs is for back end not for front end, so I would say no

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn — Node.js is for running software written in JavaScript. It is not limited to writing HTTP servers.

Comment: Which operating system do you target?

Comment: @Quentin when YouTube was mentioned I assumed that we meant a browser and not an app such as written with electron unless a `webview` is used. I think the OP should be more specific as to what node.js is being used for...

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn — I was assuming they were running a background app and using some OS level event monitor to capture key presses.

Comment: The only way that I'm aware of to accomplish something like this, is to write it as a Node.js addon in C++, then you can take advantage of something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797802).

Comment: @Bergi Windows and Linux. Mac, too if possible

Comment: @Thebluefish interesting. Too bad that I've absoluty no idea how to use C++. But I guess this is windows-only, or?

Comment: @Chinafreak yes, the linked Q/A is Windows-only.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I meant as nodejs from terminal/console (so basically app) and not webview.

Comment: @Thebluefish damn. But thank you! I guess I need to find this solutions for linux too.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn and I didn't mentioned YouTube. Playing video means everything, so basically youtube, media player etc.